# PowerShellRegex match and replace string in kix file

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm importing a KIX file:

```
$KIXOLD = get-content E:\File.kix
```

The file contains content such as this:

```
$ScriptVer = "12.0"              ; Current Script Version Number
```

I need to get the script version, in this case `12.0`, however that number can vary based upon which file I'm importing.

I've tried `Select-String` and regex like this:

```
$OLDVER = $KIXOLD | Select-String -Pattern "\$ScriptVer = `"\d\d\.\d`""
```

But that still grabs the entire line including `; Current Script Version Number` and not just the `$scriptver = "12.0"`

I'd imagine this has to be simple and I'm just going about it all wrong, but nothing I've tried has worked for me.

The end goal would be to just get `12.0` as an int, increment it and replace it, but I can't get that far until I can isolate the `$scriptver = "12.0"` from the rest of the multi-thousand line KIX file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
get-content "E:\File.kix" | where {$_ -like '$ScriptVer*'} | %{$_.split( '=;"')[2]}
```

Comment: This still hold onto whatever else is on the same line as the `$scriptver`

Comment: try my last proposition

Answer (score 1):

Other mehod :

```
$template=@"
{Row*:ScriptVer = "{Version:12.0}"              ; Xxx}
"@


(get-content "E:\File.kix" | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template).Row.Version
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? 
        $OLDVER = [regex]::Match($KIXOLD,"ScriptVer = ([1-9]\d.\d)").groups[1].value

Answer (score 0):

Select-String outputs Regex `MatchInfo` objects. To just get the value, you need to match against it, with a group of the text you want, then expand the match, then expand the group, then expand the value, e.g.

```
$Ver = Select-String -Path E:\File.kix -Pattern '^\$ScriptVer = "(.*?)"' | 
           Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches | 
           ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value }
```